# Provide embedded block for another site

Tags: php, javascript, architecture

I need to provide some functionality to another site.
What way is better and why?
1. Iframe
2. Provide PHP code and HTML/CSS.

I trust another site's admin.

Comment: No to me answering your question. Your reputation is appalling. The idea of this website is to give recognition to those who take the time to answer your questions. You are supposed to select their answers as correct. Go back and do it to your old questions and update this question with some code and maybe it wont get closed.

Comment: @Jivings he can't accept with less than 15 rep...

Comment: @CharlesForest I don't think that's true. http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/

Comment: @Jivings 0o got confused between vote up and Accept. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option is good but you keep all the responsabilities on your side. if an error occur, you're the only one to blame.

HOW? : you generate a regular Html page and give them an iframe. that's how facebook does it.

Option 2 is the eazy way but you talk about storing things into your DB. in this case i hope you know the guy who manage the other website.

Comment: I think that posting in an answer a link to how to accept answers on SO is both rude and irrelevant. You should add that as a comment, if ever. You're not compelled to answer to a question (and OP's not compelled to accept an answer, ethic aside)

Comment: you're right, just edited to put it on top answers. thanks for the comment, didn't tought about it.